# How do I make clicking on the second monitor screen not minimize my game?

Tags: windows-7, monitor

I recently switched over to a dual monitor setup and am still getting to know the features.  I've noticed that whenever I mouse over from a game onto a browser (Chrome) and clicked, it would minimize the game from my primary monitor (the browser being opened on my secondary monitor).
This is very annoying and I can't figure out a way to fix this.

Comment: Which games?  Often games have a fullscreen mode and a windowed mode.  You may need to be in windowed mode to select out of the game.  You could get more specific help with at least one example game.

Comment: @Brythan, you should turn that comment into answer. I think many folks, like OP, don't know the game itself is relevant. This Q may as well serve as a place for that knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

This only happens if you run a game in **full screen** mode.

If you go to options => graphics in this particular game and turn the display to **windowed** / **borderless**, it'll solve your problem.

Then the game will stay open in the background, while you can manage other programs (e.g. Chrome) and turn back to the game afterwards.

Note that if you use your mouse to scroll than this won't be a problem, most games lock the mouse to their "windowed fullscreen".

Try it out and I hope you succeed.

Comment: Other names: "Borderless Window", "Full Window", "Windowed (no border)". It's also worth noting most games older than 1~2 years do NOT have this option, and even some recent ones also don't.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information!
It's a shame some of the newer games still don't offer borderless displaying (e.g. Civ V).

Comment: Yeah, it's really a great option: runs like fullscreen, Alt-tab is instantaneous and multi monitor friendly.

Comment: @Kroltan Games like World of Warcraft have had this option forever. But you do get a slight reduction in FPS if you use it.

Comment: If your game doesn't support borderless windowed, there's a nice AutoHotKey-script that makes this option available for any application or game: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/78903-yabt-yet-another-borderless-window-toggle/.

Comment: @Michael: the slight FPS reduction is still happening in some games, but these are minor problems in conjunction to the advantage of a quick tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

I have that "problem" too, its not a problem but its really annoying sometimes. The thing is, some games only have either windowed or fullscreen mode and you can't switch to windowed borderless like in other games. Any idea how to keep it open in fullscreen?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/312575)