# How can I stop the game from minimizing whenever I click something on second screen?

Tags: team-fortress-2, ubuntu

I won't lie: I suck on TF2. And the revive time on this game is crazy long. I'd rather view discord or just read news on second screen while dead.

But unfortunately, when i click anything outside game screen, it minimizes itself, and I have to click the game icon to get it back. How can I prevent it from minimizing itself?

I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: Are you playing on Fullscreen? That's the typical culprit for me.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/how-do-i-make-clicking-on-the-second-monitor-screen-not-minimize-my-game)?

Comment: @Vemonus I'm on ubuntu :/

Comment: @arda, same deal usually, try my solution?

Comment: @ThomasCarroll It works well on windows but window spawns at a weird position on Ubuntu (below the bar and next to launcher). Though as majority of steam users use Windows and I didn't really state I was on ubuntu (ugh, how could I miss that), I accepted your answer.

Comment: @arda, ah yeah, I didn't realize you were on ubuntu. I'll leave the comment there in case any windows users drop by this post, though!

Comment: @arda, this sounds like an issue with ubuntu's desktop manager. Might be worth an ask on ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try borderless-windowed mode!

Add `-windowed -noborder` in the launch options.